# Volley loading data to sqlite randomly

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm using `Volley` to load the `JSON` string to the `SQLite`, but I faced with problem that `Volley` fill the `SQLite` fields randomly, one time one field is with `JSON` in the second time the same field is empty.

I'm thinking about implementing progress dialog, maybe `UI` thread can stop `Volley`, but I'm not sure...

My method:

```
private void loadJsonToSQLite() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    mDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);


    for (int i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++) {

        if (!mDB.isOpen()) {
            mDB = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        }

        final String urlPart = routeArray[i];
        final String urlPartReverse = routeArrayReverse[i];
        final String tableName = "[" + urlPart + "]";

        mDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (keyId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, route TEXT, routeReverse TEXT)");


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + urlPart,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(response);

                        if (m.find()) {
                            String extracted = m.group(1).trim();
                            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

                            initialValues.put("keyId", 1);
                            initialValues.put("route", extracted);


                            if (!mDB.isOpen()) {
                                mDB = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                            }
                            mDB.insert(tableName, null, initialValues);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);
        mDB.close();


        StringRequest stringRequestReverse = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + urlPartReverse,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(response);

                        if (m.find()) {
                            String extracted = m.group(1).trim();
                            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

                            initialValues.put("routeReverse", extracted);


                            if (!mDB.isOpen()) {
                                mDB = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                            }
                            mDB.update(tableName,initialValues,null,null);
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequestReverse);
        mDB.close();

    }


}
```

Maybe I'm wrong somewhere with `Volley`?

I have `JSON` strings in different links-ending, because of that I'm using loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it myself, simply add second loop, as I understood 2 `Volley` requests can live in one loop